# what is Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException: value issue?

Tags: react-native

I have a react native application in production and it is crashing. I have added crashlytics to the app which gave this crash report.
`Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException: value`

attaching full crash report.

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException: value
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue(ReadableNativeMap.java:109)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue(ReadableNativeMap.java:113)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getDouble(ReadableNativeMap.java:150)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.ValueAnimatedNode.<init>(ValueAnimatedNode.java:27)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.createAnimatedNode(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:85)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$4.execute(NativeAnimatedModule.java:208)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$3.execute(NativeAnimatedModule.java:154)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$UIBlockOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:498)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:779)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:888)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2200(UIViewOperationQueue.java:42)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:948)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:28)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:174)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:84)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:997)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:728)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```